# Can I remove the tiny amount of wiggle in the focus ring of my brand new lens?

Tags: focus, lens-design, lens-construction

I just purchased a Samyang 24mm T1.5 lens and the focus ring is not 100% solid and smooth, there is a tiny amount of give in the vertical direction (perpindicular to the horizontal direction the ring spins in order to focus).

When I pick up the lens I hear a tiny sound that is not present in my other Samyang cine lenses and have used another Samyang 24mm T1.5 lens before and the focus ring was perfect.

Is this something I can tighten up myself? Or something a camera shop can do? Otherwise is there reason to return the lens and buy another one (this would be an inconvenience that I'd prefer to avoid, but this would also be my most expensive lens so I don't want to pay for a crummy lens).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt there is much you can personally do about it without risking the warranty on the lens.  If your other lenses from the same manufacturer don't have that problem, I'd suggest calling up their customer service and asking about it.  Chances are they can help you more than we can in terms of if this is normal and what the best way to get it serviced or replaced is.

Comment: I think you're totally right. Samyang lenses are given a 1 year warranty by the company that owns Rokinon, Elite Brands Inc.